# want to change the fields of email sending from contact us page

Tags: magento-1.9

I created Contact us cms page as it is not defined.My fields in email sending are 
           Name-
           Email-
           Telephone-
           Comment-
I want to change the email fields are 
           Name-
           Email-
           Telephone-
           Message-

Comment: do you want to change the field label name?

Comment: field label name I changed but when mail send to my gmail it has columns as earliear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please follow these steps:**

**STEP 1**

> **Admin Panel** => **System** => **Transactional E-mails** and click **Add New Template** and from the **Template** drop-down box select **Contact Form** then **Load** Template. Under template change Comment to Message

[image]

**STEP 2**

> **System** => **Configuration** and select **Contacts**. Then under the **Email Options**, select your new template under the **Email Template** drop-down and click on Save Config.

[image]

Comment: same thing I also do but i want some changes like instead of Telephone I want to print Message or anything like Subject.

Comment: I make a message field in code but this not working. Thats what I want.

Comment: are you using custom contact form? can i have the link please

Comment: I sorry I cant provide link but this code I have written in form.phtml file


<label for="subject"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                </div>

Comment: did you change this Subject: {{var data.subject}} at admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142281/discussion-between-bachcha-singh-and-rishu-singh).

Comment: hey @bachcha Singh can you provide me answer for this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581344/want-to-get-success-message-above-or-below-the-form